# Bypass Authentication for testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, httpcookie

We have an MVC CMS app, which communicates through Web API to custom external Identity Management system (signicat-based). That IdM system exposes auth cookie, which we use for authentication back and forth.

The CMS website also requires an "auth bypass" functionality for testers, that means I would like to enter some personal number in a textbox on login page and then get logged in bypassing IdM. How can I generate my own identity cookie on the CMS backend side, so CMS would treat it then as valid and allow me to use any of [Authorize] classes / methods?